# How can I measure(length) line of segment in postgis?

Tags: postgis

This is my first question.
I wonder that, how can I get length of line's segment?

[image]

Yellow line is my road.
blue Points are my start and end points. So I want to measure point1 and point2 between route.This points are variable. So I ll select them.
How can I get it with postgis query ?

I UPDATE MY QUESTION. :)

Comment: Do you have an attribute that distinguishes the blue from the yellow?

Comment: I update my question. I have only one line. Blue points on yellow line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my solution.

```
select ST_Length(ST_AsText(ST_Line_Substring(line,ST_Line_Locate_Point(line,ST_ClosestPoint(line,strtpoint )),ST_Line_Locate_Point(line,ST_ClosestPoint(line,endpoint ))))as cizgi_uzunlugu FROM ( SELECT 'POINT(30 30)'::geometry As strtpoint,'POINT(110 0)'::geometry As endpoint,'LINESTRING(0 0, 0 30, 30 30, 30 50, 90 50, 90 60, 110 60, 110 0, 150 0, 150 30)'::geometry As line) As foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would try:

1. [ST_PointN()](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_PointN.html)
   to get desired vertices
2. [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_MakeLine.html)
   with points acquired in previous step
3. [ST_Length](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Length.html) with line acquired in previous step to get the final length.